# ASP.NET CORE 2.2 ( & 3.x) WEB API to use Razor engine for generating report

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages, razorengine

I am developing a project using ASP.NET CORE 2.2 (soon upgrade to 3.x) and Angular 8 as front end. I need to generate html for email and reporting. So I think I could use Razor Engine for it, could I mix Web Api and Razor just for generating the report ?
If yes, could you show me how to do that ? or some tutorial to implement that.

I never touched Razor or ASP.NET MVC before.

Edited:
Suppose my Controller has this code

```
public class ValuesController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet("testView")]
    public IActionResult Test(){
        return View();
    }
}
```

and my Views/Values/Test.cshtml

```
<html><body><strong>Hello World</strong></body></html>
```

Now what I want is to render Test.csthml to string and later I will transform to pdf or xls or docx with my other module.
How to get View() to return string that contains rendered html.

Comment: Yes you can.... But we can only help you if you post an example of what you have tried so far.

Comment: I am looking how to generate html with razor because I haven't found any tutorial in it. That's why i am asking.

Comment: As a matter of fact they will ask for a full sample before helping.

Comment: I can tell you one thing in ASP.NET Core you can have API controllers and MVC controllers. Inherit Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ControllerBase to create controllers without View support.  Inherit Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controller for controllers with View support.

Comment: I have add some code .. simple one since I am still new with this MVC. I used to play with JSON